# how i can remove <a> link which have specific class and title and also rmove the next span

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a third part web application. and inside the Breadcrumb navigation i will get something as follow:-

[image]

now i want to remove the link which have title = `KB` and also the next span which contain `>`

so my breadcrumb will look something as follow:-

```
Info Hub > Home
```

instead of

```
Info Hub > kb > Home
```

so can anyone adivce how i can achieve this using CSS at first place, if not possible to do it using javascript ?

Comment: What do you mean when you say `third part web application`? What you're trying to do seems just a weird way of hacking solution, instead of getting to the core of the problem.

Comment: @lonut this is a sharepoint web application, and i am using its defualt breadcrumb.. but sometimes it will show unnecessary link as kb... so i can write custom css and custom javascript to override the default behavioure.. so it is not a hack,, as the breadcrumb can not be modified in any other way..

Comment: @johnG what Ionut is saying is correct. What you are wanting to do if a dirty frontend hack. The issue must be resolved from the CMS side, SharePoint developer will know how to do that.

Comment: Can't you resolve this from term store managment?

Comment: @NitinSuri i am a SP with 5 years of experience. now in 2013 sharepoint stop to provide built-in breadcrumbs. but still we can use the old markup to provide the breadcrumb back. but it will come with issues and bugs and solving this required css/javascript.  here is a link which talk about this https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=12&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiz-fbLlPLUAhUlD8AKHfdpA5gQFghdMAs&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgeekswithblogs.net%2Fvenkatx5%2Farchive%2F2015%2F04%2F30%2Fenable-breadcrumb--navigate-up-on-sharepoint-2013.aspx&usg=AFQjCNFCNkGcg4gzATnFqnzYgngaihjugQ

Comment: @user5014677 term store is not related to my issue.. and the site i am working on is a enterprise wiki and i am not using any term store...

Comment: @user5014677 did not get your point ... modifying the built-in breadcrum is not an option ... the only way to do this is to write custom css against the built-in markup ... now edit you above comment and remove un-suitable words...

Comment: @user5014677 again this can not be dome using sharepoint.. as the built-in breadcrumb can not be modified .................

Comment: @user5014677 not sure why you had to reply in a negative way... I do have SP experience, and yes starting from SP 2013 SharePoint remove the built-in breadcrumb navigation support... now the original question is trying to find a workaround to remove what is said to be an unwanted link.... and I think the author point that term store is not related to this issue is quite correct..

Comment: Since I didn't got any response I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.your-breadcrumb-wrapper span:nth-child(2),
.your-breadcrumb-wrapper span:nth-child(3) {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: i do not want to always remove the links based on their location and this might change .. as i mentioned inside my question i need this to be based on the link title which is "kb"..